# Is applying pre-trained model on a different type of corpus called transfer learning?

Tags: nlp, transfer-learning

I trained my classification model on corpus A and evaluated it on corpus B.

I do it, because for corpus A I have a lot more labeled sentences than for B. Nature of sentences used in A is different than sentences using in B. A has name of products from e-shop, B has names of products as they appear in shopping lists, with all slang, abbreviations, spelling errors and private notes.

Am I doing transfer learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic concept of transfer learning is: **Storing knowledge gained from solving one problem and applying it to different but related problem**

I guess to be precise this is called Transductive Transfer Learning. In this we learn from the already observed training dataset and then predict the labels of the testing dataset. Even though we do not know the labels of the testing datasets, we can make use of the patterns and additional information present in this data during the learning process.

Refer: [Ruder](https://ruder.io/thesis/neural_transfer_learning_for_nlp.pdf#page=64)

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation.

Comment: Ur Welcome if it solved your query accept the answer so that it can be useful for others :)